# hundreds of select 0 statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

While profiling a postgres server I have noticed hundreds of `SELECT 0 FROM x WHERE ....` statements that are taking up a significant amount of processing time (>1000 ms). All sql statements are generated using active record and rails.

What is active record doing that could generate a `SELECT 0` statement?

Comment: This question has been here for a while.  I'd love to know the answer, too.  Does anyone know?